# Change Text in directive

Tags: angularjs

How can I change something (for instance the color) in the directive?

I have a controller which gets after every 3 seconds new data (eye Positions)

```
   myApp.controller('MainController', function ($scope, $interval, externalService, eyeTrackerService) {
    $rootScope.gazePoints = [];
    var size = 4;
    var analyze = function () {
        if ($rootScope.gazePoints.length > size) {

            $scope.gazeArea = eyeTrackerService.getGazePoints($scope.gazePoints);
            //reduce data in array
            $scope.gazePoints.splice(0, 3);
        }
    };

    var eyeTrackerData = function () {
        externalService.getData().then(function (eyeTrackerData) {

            var eyetracker = eyeTrackerData.data.EyeTracker;
            var gaze_X = (eyetracker.X_left + eyetracker.X_right) * 0.5 * screen.availWidth;
            var gaze_Y = (eyetracker.Y_left + eyetracker.Y_right) * 0.5 * screen.availHeight;

            $scope.gazePoints.push({ x: gaze_X, y: gaze_Y });
            analyze();
        });
    };

      $interval(eyeTrackerData, 3000)
    });
```

The service gets an array of gazePoints and have to analyse if the user is looking at the panel:

```
    myApp.service('eyeTrackerService', function ($rootScope) {
    this.getGazePoints = function (gazePoints) {
        var counter = 0;

        var date = $rootScope.rect;
        for (var i = 0; i < gazePoints.length; i++) {
            var x = gazePoints[i].x;
            var y = gazePoints[i].y;

            if (x >= date.left && x <= date.right && y >= date.top && y < date.bottom) {
                counter =+ 1;
                console.log("is watching");
                if(counter  == 5){
                     ///Here it should call the directive and change the color
                } 

            }

            else {
                console.log("is not watching")
            }
        }
    }
});
```

my directive:

```
myApp.directive('dateInfo', function ($rootScope, $interval) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
        },

        templateUrl: '123/Scripts/directives/html/dateInfo.html',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            $interval(function () {
                $rootScope.rect = element[0].getBoundingClientRect();
                //Here i want to change the color 
                //for example a scope.changetext(); but how??

            }, 3000);
        }
      };
    });
```

my html-file:

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">

  <div class="panel-heading">MyPanel</div>      
  <div class="panel-body">
    <input id="test" name="test">
  </div>
</div>
```

I know it´s a lot of code. But as you can see the directive are also called after every second to get the current position of the panel.

Now I want to change the color in the panel, after the counter is == 5

What is the best solution in that case? I heard it not good to change the text in the controller.

Comment: Where do you use the directive?

Comment: in the index.html.  there I defined a tag <div class container date-Info></div>

Answer (score 0):

Inside the interval, use

```
$interval(function () {
        $rootScope.rect = element[0].getBoundingClientRect();
        element.addClass('someClassThatSetsColor');
    }, 3000);
```

You can set the class based on a parameter of your choice, say if it's not looking you'll set a class that changes the color to red, or whatever.

Comment: in the service i have to set a flag and ask in directive if the flag is true, after that it the directive should make changes. That is important. Should i use a rootScope for that again?